# How to download selected records from an XLSX file using PhpSpreadSheet

Tags: xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I want to read an xlsx file in php. The XLSX file contains data with some formatting like styling of certain parts of the text with a colour code. There is a column in the XLSX which I use as a filtering criteria. I want to download only the data rows which meet this filtering criteria, like say name of a city. This downloaded file must retain the format of the colour-coded data like styling of text if present in any cell.

I am using a library known as PhpSpreadSheet with the below code. I am able to filter data by reading the xlsx file as an array and then filter the data and copy it to another file but by doing so I loose the data formatting like text styling, etc. So the problem is losing the formatting of the original XLSX when I use any kind of filtering logic. The reason I am using XLSX is to allow the format to be retained, with csv I am unable to get the colour-coding so I have to use XLSX.

I greatly appreciate any guidance.

`*/
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
​
$inputFileName = '../out/';
​
class MyReadFilter implements \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter {
​
public function readCell($columnAddress, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
if ($row <= 10) {
if (in_array($columnAddress,range('A','R'))) {
return true;
}
}
return false;
}
}

```
        $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
        $reader->setReadFilter( new MyReadFilter() );
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
```

​
//Store data from the activeSheet to the variable in the form of Array
$data = array(1,$sheet->toArray(null,true,true,true));
$data1 = json_encode($data);
$data1 = json_decode($data1,true);
$data2 = json_encode($data1[1]);
$data2 = json_decode($data2,true);
// print_r($data2);
​
//reading a template file
$spreadsheet1 = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('../out/test.xlsx');
$sheet1 = $spreadsheet1->getActiveSheet();
​
//creating first header row
$sheet1->setCellValue('A1',$data2[1]['A']);
$sheet1->setCellValue('B1',$data2[1]['B']);

​
//filter data according to decision column
$filter="Not Relevant";
​
// coppying data
$count=1;
$rcount=2;
foreach($data2 as $d){
if($d['P']==$filter && $count>1){
$sheet1->setCellValue('A'.$rcount,$d['A']);
$sheet1->setCellValue('B'.$rcount,$d['B']);

```
            $rcount++;
        }
        $count++;
    }
```

​
//creating writer fo copy filtered data into new file
​
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet1, "Xlsx");
$writer->save("../out/testxlsx.xlsx");

`

Answer (score 0):

a way you can try is to load the entire xlsx file and then delete rows which you dont want. My example checks column A for 'Not Relevant' This will preserve cellformating as fillcolor or fontcolor.
a little sidenote... dont putting obviously effort in formating your question will result in no answers or further help, no one will do 3 jobs for you, formating the question, try to understand it and code a result.

```
$path               = '1.xlsx';
$target_dir         = '2.xlsx'; 
$template_file_type = IOFactory::identify($path);
$reader             = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$excel_obj          = $reader->load($path);
$sheet              = $excel_obj->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow         = $sheet->getHighestRow();

for($row=1; $row < $highestRow; ++$row){
    $value = $excel_obj->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
    if ($value == 'Not Relevant') {
        $excel_obj->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row, 1);
        $row = $row-1;// for correcting index
    }
}

$objWriter          = new Xlsx($excel_obj);
$objWriter->save($target_dir);
```